# Remove a function from an element - tried unbind unsuccessfully

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the jQuery function below attached to all div's with a particular class. When a box is ticked I want to remove this function from the div's so it no longer runs.

I have tried `unbind` in various ways, but I am obviously getting the syntax wrong somewhere.

Also as you can see the function is not bound to the div's using `bind` so I am not even sure that unbind is the correct way to do this. I have Googled the hell out of it and all that comes up is `unbind`?

Code below:

```
$.fn.simpleTabs = function(){ 

       //Stuff

});

$("div[class^='widget']").simpleTabs();
```

All advice appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You seem to confuse event handler binding with applying arbitrary functions to selections. You are not binding any function here, you are "only" calling  `simpleTabs` on the selected elements.

Comment: @Felix Ah OK... So how do I stop "calling" this function on selected elements?

Comment: To stop calling a function you just don't execute it again your code.  If I guessed correctly, what you actually mean is that you are making changes to the element inside of the simpleTabs function. you then want to undo these changes. If thats the case, then you need to implement a 'destroy' function for the simpletabs, as is done in standard jquery plugins. you may want to read into writing jquery plugins, as it seems that this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CodeToad Yep... When you say it like that it I actually realise all I need to do is remove, unbind, or revert all the stuff that function does.

Comment: @superphonic: You only did once, you can't stop it. If you want to stop what the call started, we'd need to know what `simpleTabs` does.

Comment: In that case it depends on *what* you are doing inside that function.

Comment: read this: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/. best practice is to write a self contained plugin that can undo the changes that it made to the target object.  quick and dirty option is to write a function called removeSimletabs() that returns object to its prior state